# Python 3: How to check if the item from list is in list and print it

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists, which contains coordinates

```
points = [[5821, 293], [3214, 872], [4218, 820], [1223, 90], [7438, 820]]
```

and I need to find *pair of lists* with the same **point[i][1]** and then print both of them. This coordinates are given just for instance. In the code they're given randomly.
How to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your intent a little?

Comment: You're trying to find all coordinates with the same y value, then print them?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson yes. I'm new in programming don't know a lot yet

Comment: Your question should give the answer for the example you show.  Then it should some code that constitutes a serious attempt but does not work.  SO is not a code-writing service, especially not for what looks like a homework problem.  To get started, imagine you have a stack of cards, each with one pair of coordinates.  What would you do to solve the problem.  There are two different possible approaches.

Comment: There cannot be more than two occurrences of a same Y value right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to create a series of pairs between each two items, and filter out only those with the same second item:

```
from itertools import combinations
result = [x for x in combinations(points, 2) if x[0][1] == x[1][1]]
```

Comment: And if I'm not allowed to use itertools?

Comment: You can do the same thing with a pair of nested loops and a regular `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but here is my approach.

I use **python 3.5.2**, by the way.

If your intent is to capture all lists with [1] or y-coordinate (depending on how you look at it) with a value of 820, then the code could be:

```
for i in points:
    if i[1] == 820:
        print(i)
```

Comment: I'm guessing OP doesn't want to just capture y-coordinates that are 820. It should probably be more general.

Comment: or something like this:

for i in points:
    for j in points:
        if i[1] == j[1] and i != j:
            print(j)

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy and efficient way to do what you want with your current data structure.

You can either use an inefficient method (`O(N**2)`), or convert your data to another format where you can use a more efficient algorithm.

[Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912344/1405065) is a good way to do an `O(N**2)` search, so I'll offer a solution that uses a dictionary to make the checking fast:

```
def find_matches(points):
    dct = {}
    for x, y in points:
        for other_x in dct.setdefault(y, []):
            yield (x, y), (other_x, y)
        dct[y].append(x)
```

This is a generator, which will `yield` pairs of points with matching `y` values. It should use `O(N)` space and `O(N+R)` time (for `N` input points and `R` pairs of matches).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will work for you:

```
 second_list = [] 
 the_list = [[5821, 293], [3214, 872], [4218, 820], [1223, 90], 
 [7438, 820]]
 for i in the_list:
      second_list.append(i[1])

 repeated = []
 the_new_list = sorted(second_list, key=int)
 for i in range(len(the_new_list)):
     if i + 1 < len(the_new_list):
          if the_new_list[i] == the_new_list[i+1]:
               repeated.append(the_new_list[i])

 for i in the_list:
      if i[1] in repeated:
          print(i)
```

second_list stores the y-coordinates of your list. Then, the program sorts the list of y-coordinates in ascending order and appends them to the_new_list. Finally, we loop over the_new_list and see if any numbers after each other are equal, and if so, append them to the list repeated. Then, we loop over the_list and see if any points are in repeated. If so, we print the entire thing. I hope that helps.